# Apache Modal Logon Window

Tags: apache-httpd

Ubuntu 14.04
Apache 2.4.7

I began to create a modal logon page on Apache to secure a site and notice some differences in installation that I need some clarification before proceeding.

I followed this procedures, which may be outdated and before messing anything up I wanted to check
http://melandri.net/2012/04/29/using...mod-auth-form/

For the modal logon page to function the following modules entries are needed in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file.

```
LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
LoadModule session_cookie_modules/mod_session_cookie.so
```

However, there is not modules folder in /etc/apache2 with this installation.

I did located these modules in /usr/lib/apache2/modules

I tried to load them from the folder, but not sure if it worked or not, I checked to see what modules were loaded with apache2ctl -M and they were not listed.

Can this folder just be copied over to /etc/apache2?

or do I need to re-compile Apache with those modules? Which I read somewhere was not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu), modules are configured using symlinks in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`, pointing to files in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`. If you look in the latter, you should see `auth_form.load`, `session.load` etc. which correspond to the modules your looking for.

To enable them, use `a2enmod` (Apache 2 enable module):

```
sudo a2enmod auth_form
sudo a2enmod session
sudo a2enmod request
sudo a2enmod session_cookie
```

The command to disable a module is `a2dismod`.